# Is the Micro Four Thirds standard specification public?

Tags: micro-four-thirds, specification

I want to get more knowledge of M43 standard, and I assumed that as a standard it should be available with all specifications for the public — or at least for purchase — but couldn't get one. The official website http://www.four-thirds.org/en/microft/ gives only a high-level overview. I want to understand the communication protocol.

Where one can get standard documentation? Is it public?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Micro Four Thirds is not an open standard. The specification is available to member companies, [which are listed here](http://www.four-thirds.org/en/contact/group.html). It's not a tiny list, but it's not large, either.

Your best bet is found [on the contact page](http://www.four-thirds.org/en/contact/index.html), which says (sic):

> **To Manufacturers considering developing or selling the Four Thirds compliance product.**
>
> For inquiries on Four Thirds System standard, please contact the following E-mail address.
>   four-thirds@ot.olympus.co.jp